# How do I add custom font in React Native not using Xcode?

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, reactjs

Is there a way to add custom font in React Native in Atom editor and not using Xcode?

Answer (score 5):

There is an easier way of doing things through command line using `rnpm`. It adds fonts to both android and ios. Place the font you want to add to a suitable location inside your project directory. In your package.json just add the following:

`...
    "rnpm": {
          "assets": ["path/to/your/font/directory"]
    },
...`

Then from command line do: `rnpm link`

you can now happily use your fonts in your app.

Note: you have to have rnpm installed for this to work. 
Just do `npm install -g rnpm`

Here is the documentation: https://github.com/rnpm/rnpm#advanced-usage

Comment: I have done this method and still get Unrecognised Font

Comment: which font are you using? and what are you giving as font name in `fontFamily: 'my_font"`? @Paul'Whippet'McGuane

Comment: fontFamily: 'Quicksand-Bold'

Comment: @Paul'Whippet'McGuane you can checkout if the font name is correct or not using carlos-quiroga answer below

Answer (score 1):

The way without edit package.json is:

1. Install in your proyect react-native-vector-icons (`npm install --save react-native-vector-icons`).
2. Move the fonts into `node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts`.
3. run `react-native link`.
4. run `react-native run-ios`

The problem is that the name of the fonts is different than the file name. The way to show all names of the installed fonts is modify `AppDelegate.m` and put the loop:

```
   for (NSString *familyName in [UIFont familyNames]) {
        for (NSString *fontName in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:familyName]) {
            NSLog(@"%@", fontName);
        }
    }
```

For icons fonts the name is the same.

Comment: This is incorrect. You should checkout my answer below.

Comment: you don't need to install react-native-vector-icons just to add fonts using rnpm.

Answer (score 0):

Not Possible to add Custom Font iOS .
You are using Xcode then add Font in native app

- Copy your font file into resources
- Add a key to your Info.plist file called UIAppFonts. ("Fonts provided by application)Make this key an array
- For each font you have, enter the full name of your font file (including the extension) as items to the UIAppFonts array

Comment: It is possible to add it using rnpm.