# Adding fonts to a react-native project

Tags: xcode, git, fonts, react-native

I do know how to add fonts to a react-native project.
I have added them and it works on my computer.
When I push it to a branch, the person who clones it is not able to open the app on the simulator, because it gives an error message like so:

> The following build commands failed:
>       CpResource /Users/asciiman/Downloads/Raleway/Raleway-Light.ttf build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SomeProject.app/Raleway-Light.ttf
>       CpResource /Users/asciiman/Downloads/Lato/Lato-BlackItalic.ttf build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SomeProject.app/Lato-BlackItalic.ttf
>   (2 failures)....

I followed the procedure to add fonts to my project from [here](https://github.com/refinery29/react-native-cheat-sheet).

Comment: checkout this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38564125/how-do-i-add-custom-font-in-react-native-not-using-xcode/38587218#38587218

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you add the fonts from a directory outside of your git project? Maybe the actual fonts have not been tracked in git and so the person cloning does not have them?

In Xcode there is a checkbox that says something like "Copy items if needed" (when adding files) which should copy the files to your Xcode project, maybe that was not checked and so it is referencing a file outside of your Xcode and git project.

Comment: Yes, I did add the fonts from a directory outside of my git project. I did do 'git add .'. 
I did'nt check the checkbox which says "Copy items if needed".
Should try that.

Comment: Definitely the exact solution, I have a custom font and I am so bothered why my build failed . . When I read this answer I realized that I imported my custom font from the desktop so git is trying to copy a file that is outside my project and that causes the build to fail . . so I copied the custom font inside the project, push the changes to git and there everything works like a charm . . Thanks a lot @David :)